# Vue.js 2 - Transition-Group Fade Out Appearing in Wrong Position

Tags: jquery, css, vue.js, vuejs2, css-transitions

I have the following vue.js markup to iterate a list. I've applied a transition-group element using animated.css as follows.

When I delete an item, the correct item is deleted but the fade effect appears at the bottom of the list and not on the item that's deleted. Can any one help as I'm new to vue.js and can't seem to find much material on it.

```
<ul class="list-inline">
   <transition-group  enter-active-class="animated fadeIn" leave-active-class="animated fadeOut">  
      <li v-for="(comment, index) in comments" :key="comment.id">

         <span v-html="comment.comment"></span>

         <div class="actions clearfix">
               <a href="#" 
                  v-bind:data-comment-id="comment.id" 
                  v-on:click.prevent="delete(comment.id)">
                  Delete
              </a>
         </div> 

      </li>
    </transition-group> 
</ul>

 var vm =  new Vue({
        el: '#root',
        data: {
           comments: [
                    {
                      "id": 2,
                      "comment": "blah...",
                    },
                    {
                      "id": 4,
                      "comment": "blah...",
                    }
                    {
                      "id": 6,
                      "comment": "blah...",
                    }
            ]
         },
         methods: {
            delete: function (id) {
                 axios.post("api/comments/delete?id=" + id)
                        .then((response) => {

                            var index = _.findIndex(this.comments, function(comment) { return comment.id === id; });
                            this.comments.splice(index, 1);
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                        }); 
            }

        }
 });
```

Comment: Not sure if from copying over or not but you have a closing `transition` tag but it should be `</transition-group>`.

Comment: @lamelemon sorry that was a typo in my post

Comment: Can you try recreating the issue in a jsfiddle or something.  I've tried [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wzcfe7kc/1/) and it seems to work fine.

Comment: @lamelemon i just noticed I missed the `:` from `:key="comment.id"` which was causing the abnormal behaviour. Thanks for your help buddy.

Comment: I want to also note that setting :key="index" will cause a similar (if not identical) issue.